# Convert Base64 string to PNG image and respond as http Response - Go language

Tags: go

I am trying to convert a base64 encoding to a png image and ouput the image as response for a web request. Can I do this without creating a file in the server?

the 'ServeFile' of http works only when the image is saved as a file. but, I would like to decode the base64 string to image data and then directly write that to the output.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [base64.NewDecoder](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#NewDecoder), for example :

```
func Handler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    //in this example the client submits the base64 image, however
    // you can use any io.Reader and pass it to NewDecoder.
    dec := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, req.Body)
    res.Header().Set("Content-Typee", "image/png")
    io.Copy(res, dec)
}
```